# Should I use a cognito app secret for a mobile app?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

The Secret is optional, the docs [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/user-pool-settings-client-apps.html) under `Specifying User Pool App Settings` state:

> When you create an app, you can optionally choose to create
> a secret for that app. If a secret is created for the app,
> the secret must be provided to use the app.
> **Browser-based applications** written in JavaScript may
> not need an app with a secret.
>
> Secrets cannot be changed after an app is created.
> You can create a new app with a new secret if you want
> to rotate the secret that you are using. You can also
> delete an app to block access from apps that
> use that app client ID.

Specifically they call out the exception for **browser-based applications** based apps as the source is readily available and the secret can be plucked from there.

With a mobile app, searching for the strings from the compiled app is probably akin to finding the secret in browser based applications; it's slightly more work to be sure.

Anyway, is the recommendation for mobile applications to just forgo the secret?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend to go with secret, so you can keep control of applications that need to get access and that need to get blocked.

If you want version 1.3 or lower to block access and only 1.4 need to be accessed, you can create a new app secret for 1.4 and remove all the secrets below 1.3 and request the users to upgrade to latest app to access newer version.

This is also help to deny access for specific version if that has a bug or any exploits.

Hope it helps.